# Função async retornando antes do resultado

Tags: javascript, async

Tenho essa função em JS, utilizando biblioteca Forge, para geração de par de chaves. O problema que ao tentar utilizar a função async para realizar a geração, a função está retornando antes de gerar o resultado.

```
function generateKeys(keySize, storageName) {
    var rsa = forge.pki.rsa;
    // var keys = forge.pki.rsa.generateKeyPair(keySize);
    var p1 = rsa.generateKeyPair({bits: keySize, workers: -1}, function(err, keypair) {
        var privateKey = keypair.privateKey;
        var publicKey = keypair.publicKey;
        sessionStorage.setItem(storageName, JSON.stringify(privateKey));

        var csr = forge.pki.createCertificationRequest();
        csr.publicKey = publicKey;
        csr.sign(privateKey);

        // convert certification request to PEM-format
        var certReqPem = forge.pki.certificationRequestToPem(csr);
        console.log(certReqPem);
        return certReqPem;
    });    
};
```

Recebo esse retorno no meu HTML para encaminhar para um form PHP, porém, está vindo NULL, mas se eu mandar printar, eu vejo que ele manda Null, e depois printa no console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é necessário async/await para o cenário que você deseja. O problema está na utilização da sobrecarga incorreta para o que necessida, da função 'rsa.generateKeyPair'.

Você pode utilizar a mesma função rsa.generateKeyPair sem necessidade de passar um callback e está tudo resolvido.

Abaixo envio o código e com um teste logo abaixo (só copiar e colar):

```
function generateKeys(keySize, storageName) {

    var rsa = forge.pki.rsa;
    // var keys = forge.pki.rsa.generateKeyPair(keySize);
    var keypair = rsa.generateKeyPair({bits: keySize, workers: -1});    

    var privateKey = keypair.privateKey;
    var publicKey = keypair.publicKey;
    ssessionStorage.setItem(storageName, JSON.stringify(privateKey));

    var csr = forge.pki.createCertificationRequest();
    csr.publicKey = publicKey;
    csr.sign(privateKey);

    // convert certification request to PEM-format
    var certReqPem = forge.pki.certificationRequestToPem(csr);

    return certReqPem;    
};
```

Testando:

```
const x = generateKeys(...);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: Realmente funciona, meu questionamento é o seguinte: necessito de desempenho, qual abordagem mais correta? Parece que a async é mais rápida

Comment: Então Vinicius, isso é muito relativo e depende também se a biblioteca que você está utilizando possui o recurso assíncrono ou você necessitaria fazer um wrap para retorno de uma Promise.

Você ganha desempenho com recursos assíncronos quando faz sentido você colocar tarefas para execução em paralelo. Mas no seu caso, você precisa aguardar o retorno da chave para continuar o seu programa, então não existe a necessidade de tarefas paralelas.

Recomendo, se desejar, a leitura desse artigo: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas

Comment: Acho que a minha resposta está correta e a que você marcou como correta está errada, porque o 'await' recomendado na resposta do amigo é irrelevante e não era necessário, mesmo a função sendo async. Tire o 'await' e comprove, isso porque a função 'generateKeyPair' não retorna uma Promise para necessitar de 'await'

Answer (score 1):

Pode tentar usar async/await da seguente maneira

```
function async generateKeys(keySize, storageName) {
    var rsa = forge.pki.rsa;
    // var keys = forge.pki.rsa.generateKeyPair(keySize);
    var keypair = await rsa.generateKeyPair({bits: keySize, workers: -1});
    var privateKey = keypair.privateKey;
    var publicKey = keypair.publicKey;
    sessionStorage.setItem(storageName, JSON.stringify(privateKey));

    var csr = forge.pki.createCertificationRequest();
    csr.publicKey = publicKey;
    csr.sign(privateKey);

    // convert certification request to PEM-format
    var certReqPem = forge.pki.certificationRequestToPem(csr);
    console.log(certReqPem);
    return certReqPem;   
};
```

Comment: No HTML está assim: var publicKeyPem = generateKeys(keySize, "privateKeyPem"); Quando faço console.log nessa variavel, está vindo uma promessa no estado pending.

Comment: Por isso ao ser uma promise, vc tem que executar com async/await para fazer a execuçao da promesa aguardando seu fim [funçoes async](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: Hum, você diz utilizar .then? estou tentando, mas sem muito sucesso

Comment: Nao, VC pode Fazer con eu indico na resposta, com async e await

Comment: Eu fiz como está ali, ele está retornando uma promessa, como disse na primeira resposta

Comment: Na primera resposta vc nao faze `var publicKeyPem = await generateKeys(keySize, "privateKeyPem");`

Comment: com o await da este erro: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators, o que é bem estranho, pois a função está declarada como async

Comment: Pegue a funçao para ajudar

Comment: Ah consegui, o problema que eu estava chamando isso em outra função no HTML, ai coloquei async nela também, e await como dito anteriormente, funcionou, valeu.